# How to show the explicit form of rotation operator?

Tags: sequences-and-series, operator-theory, taylor-expansion

Suppose $P_R(\alpha) f(x,y)=f(x\cos\alpha +y\sin\alpha, y\cos\alpha-x\sin\alpha)$

How to show that the operator $P_R(\alpha)$ has the form:

$$
P_R(\alpha)=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}(-i\alpha)^n l_z^n
$$

where $l_z=-i(x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}-y\frac{\partial}{\partial x})$.

I tried to expand the right hand side, but don't know how to collect the terms:

$$
f(x\cos\alpha +y\sin\alpha, y\cos\alpha-x\sin\alpha)
=\sum_{m,n}\frac{1}{m!n!}f^{(m,n)}(0,0)(x\cos\alpha +y\sin\alpha)^m (y\cos\alpha-x\sin\alpha)^n
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(up to factors of $i$): Start by showing that $l_z = {\partial\over{\partial \alpha}}$ and then show that $e^{\beta {\partial \over {\partial \alpha}} }$ is the shift operator, and satisfies $ e^{\beta {\partial \over {\partial \alpha}} } g(\alpha)=g(\alpha +\beta)$ for smooth enough $g's$. Once you've gotten that far you will notice that $P_R(\alpha)$ is essentially the shift operator.

Comment: Its an rotation operator actually.

Comment: it is a rotation in $(x,y)$ but a shift in $\alpha$

Comment: You are right, thanks. I'll try to complete the proof, if I did, I will accept your answer.

Comment: I also want to know how to do it without changing into the polar coordinates, do you know how to do it?